# exit code 208 after explicit exit 22224

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

I was just mucking around with a bash script and I had:

```
exit 22224;
```

but the actual exit code was `208`...I assume that's because `208` means "bad exit code" or something? Hard to find info on that

Comment: There is no such number as 22224 - when you're dealing with 8-bit integers, as is the case with process exit codes.  208 is simply the lowest 8 bits of that value, which is all you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UNIX exit code is stored in one byte, i.e., between 0 and 255, so anything else is truncated to that single byte. The `_exit(2)` manual page even says how:

> The value status & 0377 is  returned  to  the  parent  process  as  the process's  exit  status,  and can be collected using one of the wait(2) family of calls.

Note that "0377" is just octal for 255. Bitwise-anding with it just means take the last byte. And indeed,

> $ python -c 'print(22224 & 255)'
>
> 208

Comment: With bash: `echo $((22224 % 256))`